# Access a deeply nested field inside an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, nested, javascript-objects

I have the code below:

```
var ops = [{
    label: 'Primary Colors',
    options: [{
        label: 'Yellow',
        value: 'yellow'
    }, {
        label: 'Red',
        value: 'red'
    }, {
        label: 'Blue',
        value: 'blue'
    }],
    label: 'Secondary Colors',
    options: [{
        label: 'Pink',
        value: 'yellow'
    }, {
        label: 'Pink',
        value: 'Pink'
    }, {
        label: 'Violet',
        value: 'violet'
    }]
}
```

I want to create a variable that contains all values for the value field inside the options array like this: `value = [yellow, red, blue, yellow, pink, violet]`. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you made any attempts? If so, post them up and the community can chime in on where to go next.

Comment: You have duplicated keys inside your object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with Javascript **[foreach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)** method

```js
var ops=[{label: 'Primary Colors',
options: [{label: 'Yellow',value: 'yellow'},
{label: 'Red',value: 'red'},
{label: 'Blue',value: 'blue'}]},
{label: 'Secondary Colors',
options: [{label: 'Pink',value: 'yellow'},{label: 'Pink',value: 'Pink'},{label: 'Violet',value: 'violet'}]}];      

var arr =[];var obj = [];
arr = ops.forEach(function(o){
  var a = o.options;
  a.forEach(function(option) {
    
    obj.push(option.value);
 });
});
console.log(obj);
```

[Fiddle Working Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/saidulu401/jz9mpohy/)

**Note:** Modified data you have provided because some closing tags(}]) not in correct order.